# ConfigurableApplicationContext vs ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring

I have been learning Spring Framework for some time. But whenever I look for initialization and destruction callbacks, every example uses `ConfigurableApplicationContext` instead of `ApplicationContext`. Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 11):

Because all common implementation of ApplicationContext are in fact ConfigurableApplicationContext. Extract from javadoc for ConfigurableApplicationContext :

*SPI interface to be implemented by most if not all application contexts.*

and

*Configuration and lifecycle methods are encapsulated here to avoid making them obvious to ApplicationContext client code. The present methods should only be used by startup and shutdown code*

That means that when you *use* an application context, i.e. get beans from it you only use it as an `ApplicationContext` but when you manage its life cycle (initialization and destruction) you use methods from `ConfigurableApplicationContext`

Answer (score 2):

`ApplicationContext`: This the most powerful Container, compare to Bean-factory (Core container).

`ConfigurableApplicationContext`: One of the implementation of the `ApplicationContext` container. This container is used for Event Handling propose.

If you implement the following methods and your Bean Class extends the `ApplicationListner` interface, then when these methods are executed, your Bean will get related Events.

```
void refresh()
void close();
void shutdown();
```