# when to use configurable application context over application context?

Tags: spring

i am learning spring from quite some time now and
i have researched a lot about this,but couldn't find any satisfying answer.
**why would i want to use configurable application context?
what are the benefits?** .
also saw the documentation but couldn't understand it.

Here is what the documentation says:

> SPI interface to be implemented by most if not all application
>   contexts. Provides means to configure an application context in
>   addition to the application context client methods in the
>   ApplicationContext interface.
>
> Configuration and lifecycle methods are encapsulated here to avoid
>   making them obvious to ApplicationContext client code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ConfigurableApplicationContext vs ApplicationContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30861709/configurableapplicationcontext-vs-applicationcontext)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ApplicationContext gives you more of get/read only methods and encapsulated or doesn't allow Configuration and lifecycle methods.

e.g: you can ApplicationContext's implementation to load Configuration from XML

Most commonly used ApplicationContext implementations are

```
FileSystemXmlApplicationContext
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext
WebXmlApplicationContext
```

So all above implementation will not have methods to manage Configuration and lifecycle.

If you want more control over Life Cycle like Initialisation and Destruction, you can use `ConfigurableApplicationContext`.

Here are few examples of using ConfigurableApplicationContext

https://www.javatips.net/api/org.springframework.context.configurableapplicationcontext

I have just rephrased answer given in [this Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30861709/configurableapplicationcontext-vs-applicationcontext)